# Different hibernate properties per profile

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I've got spring boot project with Hibernate and Spring Data. There is more than one profile, so project can be run in test profile, run profile etc. Every profile needs different Hibernate properties. **Let's say I would rather like to define keep properties in .property files than Java classes.** application.properties comes with feature to specify profile as application-{profile}.properties. Unfortunately, that's not a case with hibernate.properties. Or is it? Is there a way to inject different hibernate properties per profile using .properties files?

Comment: Have you tried or selected any of the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Spring Boot (I assume yes as you tagged the question with the spring-boot tag), you can configure hibernate through the *application.properties* or *application-{profile}.properties* already loaded by Spring Boot. Just take into account there are three levels of properties supported:

- General properties for any JPA provider. Ex:

  spring.jpa.show-sql=true
- Some direct Hibernate properties. Ex:

  spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy= org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
- Other properties of the JPA provider. Those are the same properties expected by *hibernate* in your case, just prepending *spring.jpa.properties* to the property names. Ex:

  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=false

Take a look at the Spring Boot reference documentation as well as the [JpaProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties.java) boot file to see which properties are supported at the first two levels.

Answer (score 1):

There's a String Spring looks for, it's is called `persistenceXmlLocation`, you can make a `Bean` out of it and have different values based on your active profile. For example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DefaultDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "persistenceXmlLocation")
    public String persistenceXmlLocation() {
        return "classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml";
    }
}
```

Then for your different profile, `test` in this case, you'd have this:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestDatabaseConfig  {

    @Bean(name = "persistenceXmlLocation")
    public String persistenceXmlLocation() {
        return "classpath:META-INF/test-persistence.xml";
    }
}
```

You could probably also achieve this by wiring an `Environment` into your `Configuration` class and based on what profile is active return different persistence.xml locations.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easiest way by using

> maven ressource filtering

So you can add a folder **filter** under **src/main** and put all your config files for each profile inside that folder ex : (application-test.properties , application-run.properties ... ), then add this code to your pom :

```
<build>
    <!--enter code here -->
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/filters/application-${env}.properties</filter>
        </filters>

</build>
```

And so you can get your config file depending on a profile by adding **-Denv=test** for example if you want to pick the app-test file ( `mvn clean package -Denv=test`)

Comment: Nice answer. Adding some reference links would make it complete.